# How to reduce startup lag in X Mouse Button Control

Tags: windows, mouse, lag, right-click

I have used X Mouse Button control to reroute my mouse button 4 to a right click auto clicker. I did this by setting the key to rmb and making it repeat (option 6). But whenever I press the button it takes about 1 second before the thing actually auto clicks. I’ve tried adjusting the latency but that doesn’t work and I’m on the lowest latency of 0 anyways. Is there anyway to remove this startup lag?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, by changing the latency to 5 milliseconds it seems to work perfectly. I guess the 0 mm delay caused a malfunction of some kind or it may have not registered.